# AWS Lambda in dotnet core Does not seem to recognize the Cloudwatch Event Constant Value

Tags: c#, node.js, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I've setup a simple dotnet core lambda in C#. However the output of the req parameter does not contain the const value I setup in the Cloudwatch Event Rule. The NodeJs version seem to work fine. Is this a limitation for dotnet core on lambda right now, or am I missing something?

```
        public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest req, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"context: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"req: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req)}");

        var body = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "message", "hello world" }
        };

        return new APIGatewayProxyResponse
        {
            Body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body),
            StatusCode = 200,
            Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", "application/json" } }
        };
    }
```

the output of the req parameter:

```
req: 
{
"Resource": null,
"Path": null,
"HttpMethod": null,
"Headers": null,
"MultiValueHeaders": null,
"QueryStringParameters": null,
"MultiValueQueryStringParameters": null,
"PathParameters": null,
"StageVariables": null,
"RequestContext": null,
"Body": null,
"IsBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Comment: The event you are choosing is an apigateway trigger here and not a cloudwatch event. You can take the event as a Stream instead of apigatewayproxyRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the input can be taken as Stream in Lambda as mentioned in the docs here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html

Currently Dotnet Core has only the following event models as per the docs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-csharp.html

For all other events you can use Stream as the input type.

```
public async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandler(Stream req, ILambdaContext context)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem, plus, I don't like the idea of change my request `APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest` object to some kind of dictionary - that is required in order to read the constant value coming from the Cloudwatch event rule!

The key point is whenever you do a request to your lambda function *- by API Gateway proxy integration*, you'll always have some headers. So you in cases like that you can simply check if exists some header in the request object.

A sample request coming from POSTMAN *- but even coming from your UI, you'll have headers as well*.

```json
EVENT: 
{
    "Version": null,
    "RouteKey": null,
    "RawPath": null,
    "RawQueryString": null,
    "Cookies": null,
    "Headers": {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
        "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
        "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "BR",
        "Host": "t4hze5zh38.execute-api.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        "Postman-Token": "8521cbbb-a9c1-445b-b66d-f0c4bb68dbd5",
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.26.8",
        "Via": "1.1 5f69a260e7654c911054fa462ec28ae3.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
        "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "90UbnoINKvE08-56pfkJ5LSkuGWafoOUojffuKNxzzJQ6yZjNIxqAw==",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5fafd291-429d012f6903bc8d2ff8214a",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "201.71.130.111, 64.252.179.78",
        "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
    "QueryStringParameters": null,
    "RequestContext": {
        "AccountId": "644846694994",
        "ApiId": "t4hze5zh38",
        "Authorizer": null,
        "DomainName": "t4hze5zh38.execute-api.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        "DomainPrefix": "t4hze5zh38",
        "Http": null,
        "RequestId": "b0d750a7-eb7e-4871-a2c8-ba73f75c08f8",
        "RouteId": null,
        "RouteKey": null,
        "Stage": "dev",
        "Time": null,
        "TimeEpoch": 0
    },
    "Body": null,
    "PathParameters": null,
    "IsBase64Encoded": false,
    "StageVariables": null
}
```

A sample of how I'm handling it:

```
    public async Task<APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse> Handle(APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            LogFunctionMetadata(request, context);

            if (request.Headers == null)
            {
                LambdaLogger.Log("Warn Up Function");
                await _pendingReviewRepository.GetByIdAsync(Guid.Empty);
                return NoContent();
            }
            ...
        }
```

Plus, I like to do some dummy query to "warn up" my database as well. *It works very well for dynamoDb*.